# Get CPU % of given PID without psutil

Tags: python, cpu

I can't install any modules on some box, thus - I can't use `psutil`.

Need to get % of CPU usage by given PID.

One solution I see - use `subprocess`, but it looks horribly:

```
# CPU usage
cpu_percentage = subprocess.call("top -p 25393 -b -n 1 | grep -w java | awk '{print $9}'", shell=True, stdout=devnull)
print('\nCPU percentage usage by Java: %s%%' % cpu_percentage)
```

Also, such way - I can't find out how to pass variable, instead of `PID` directly (25393 in this exampel).

Comment: you could try looking through the source of psutil to see how its done there?

Comment: You know that you can install modules into a per-user `site-packages` directly which does *not* require admin privileges? Just use `easy_install --user` instead of `easy_install` (`pip` has a `--user` option too).

Comment: @JamesKent I thought about it, but hope - there is better solution...

Comment: @Bakuriu yep, but we can't do even this :-)

Comment: The way to install application specific modules in Python is virtualenv which works without root access: http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/

Comment: If you can't install stuff locally (but can paste files) just put the psutil file in the same directory and it will work :) If that's not an option either than you can put the psutil code in your file but that will get increasingly hacky ;)

Comment: @Wolph `psutil` contains some C code so you'll have to compile that for the target OS and machine.

Comment: Passing a variable is just as exactly as you did in line 3 (`print('\nCPU percentage usage by Java: %s%%' % cpu_percentage)`): `"top -p %d -b -n 1 | grep -w java | awk '{print $9}'" % PID`, where `PID` is a `int` variable.

Comment: @Bakuriu: not in all cases I believe, on Linux it works (or at least used to work) with python.

Comment: @SonicARG realy! thanks :-) `>>> subprocess.call("top -p %d -b -n 1 | grep -w 25393 | awk '{print $9}'" % int(java_pid), shell=True, stdout=devnull)` // i tried set `% java_pid` in wrong place before

Comment: @setevoy, I'm glad my help was useful. I copied the comment as an answer; if you think it was useful, please accept the answer as valid. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass the variable to a string you can format it just like you did on line 3:

```
# CPU usage

# +Apply here:
cpu_percentage = subprocess.call("top -p %d -b -n 1 | grep -w java | awk '{print $9}'" % PID, shell=True, stdout=devnull)

# +like you did here:
print('\nCPU percentage usage by Java: %s%%' % cpu_percentage)
```

`PID` should be a `int` instance for make this work